Create print method for class based on existing class (i.e., print `tibbles` longer)
I want to create a class that prints tibble objects in a certain way, essentially to print all of some data sets stored in a package when called. I am getting pretty lost as to how to make that work.
Here's my current state, having tried variations on the below to no success.
Ideally, this would print zz like a normal tbl_df but with the specified number of rows (in this example n = 3)
library(tibble)

long_tibble <- setClass(
  Class = "long_tibble",
  slots = c(tab = "tbl_df"),
  contains = "tbl_df"
)

print.long_tibble <- function(x){
  x@tab |>
    tibble::as_tibble() |>
    print(n = 3)
}

zz <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:10)
class(zz) <- "long_tibble"
zz
#> Error in x@tab: no applicable method for `@` applied to an object of class "long_tibble"

xx <- long_tibble(tab = zz)
#> Error in as(slotVal, slotClass, strict = FALSE): no method or default for coercing "long_tibble" to "tbl_df"
zz
#> Error in x@tab: no applicable method for `@` applied to an object of class "long_tibble"

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.0.2
Thoughts / prayers? 

I'm not familiar with setClass() but I think you could use the S3 method dispatch to do what you want:
library(tibble)

print.long_tibble <- function(x){
  x |>
    tibble::as_tibble() |>
    print(n = 3)
}

zz <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:10)
class(zz) <- c("long_tibble", class(zz))
zz
#> # A tibble: 10 × 1
#>       a
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
#> # ℹ 7 more rows

Just in case you missed it, print() for tibble has additional options for the number of rows and of columns to display (among other things): https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/formatting.html

Set a show method and use it in print.long_tibble.
library(tibble)

long_tibble <- setClass(
  Class = "long_tibble",
  slots = c(tab = "tbl_df"), 
  contains = "tbl_df"
)

setMethod("show", "long_tibble", function(object) {
  object@tab |>
    head(n = 3) |>
    print()
})
print.long_tibble <- function(...) show(...)

zz <- tibble::tibble(a = 1:10)
zz
#> # A tibble: 10 × 1
#>        a
#>    <int>
#>  1     1
#>  2     2
#>  3     3
#>  4     4
#>  5     5
#>  6     6
#>  7     7
#>  8     8
#>  9     9
#> 10    10

xx <- long_tibble(tab = zz)

xx
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>       a
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
show(xx)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>       a
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3
print(xx)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>       a
#>   <int>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     3

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0
